# monaca スライディングメニューページでのclickの受け取り

Tags: monaca

初歩的な質問になります。
monacaの「スライディングメニュー」のテンプレートを使い、
スライディングメニュー上にボタンを配置し、
そのクリックをindex.htmlで受け取り処理をしたいと思います。

以下のプログラムを書いたのですが、スライディングメニューのボタンをクリックしても、
クリックが受け取れません（console.log("aaa")が書き出されません）。

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * data:; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
    <script src="components/loader.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script>
        ons.bootstrap();
        $(function(){
            $('.btn1').on('click',function() {
                console.log("aaa");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ons-sliding-menu var="app.slidingMenu" menu-page="menu.html" main-page="page1.html" side="left" type="overlay" max-slide-distance="200px">
    </ons-sliding-menu>
</body>
</html>
```

menu.html

```
<ons-page style="background-color: white">
    <ons-list>
        <ons-list-item modifier="chevron" class="btn1">
            メニュー１
        </ons-list-item>
    </ons-list>
</ons-page>
```

スライディングメニュー上のクリックを受け取るには、どうすればいいのでしょうか？
どなたかお教えいただけますようお願い致します。

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

こんにちは
私はjQueryの知識がないため、記載して頂いたコードをそのまま動作させることはできないのですが、
特にjQueryを使用しなくても良いのであれば、以下のように記述してはいかがでしょうか。

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * data:; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
    <script src="components/loader.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script>
        ons.bootstrap();
        var tap = function(){
            console.log("test message");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ons-sliding-menu var="app.slidingMenu" menu-page="menu.html" main-page="page1.html" side="left" type="overlay" max-slide-distance="200px">
    </ons-sliding-menu>
</body>
</html>
```

menu.html

```
<ons-page style="background-color: white">

    <ons-list>
        <ons-list-item modifier="chevron" onclick="tap()">
            メニュー１
        </ons-list-item>
    </ons-list>

</ons-page>
```

また、jQueryが動作しないということであれば、MonacaIDEの「設定」→「JS/CSSコンポーネントの追加と削除」からjQueryのコンポーネントを追加も試してみてはいかがでしょうか。

以上です。

Comment: 教えていただいた方法でできました。ご親切にどうもありがとうございました。   
また、jqueryを使う場合、$(function() {}) ではなく、 ons.readyを使うということがわかりました。  
`<script>
        ons.bootstrap();
        ons.ready(function(){
            $('.btn1').on('click',function() {
                console.log("aaa");
            });
        });
</script>`